# JQuery plugin, multiple instances same page; apply to element classes and unique element ids; protecting options with $.data; public access functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, boilerplate

I'm authoring a JQuery plugin for this first time - almost there - and trying to find the best "boilerplate" to suit the below needs.

**Here is my problem:**

[See my JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dkg5m9h/4/)

I cannot get the plugin to work on elements by their class name.

This works:

```
var myPlugin = $('#single').myPlugin();   // Yes - it gets initialised
myPlugin.doAFunction(" Some Params ");    // Yes - public access func works
```

This **DOES NOT** work:

```
var myPluginFooClass = $('.foo').myPlugin(); // Yes, it gets initialised
myPlugin.doAFunction(" Some Params ");       // NO - now this falls over
```

Here is what I need to achieve:

- Multiple instances on the same page
- Each instance has its own variables which don't get overwritten by other instances when they are deployed (I'm using $.data)
- **Public access functions only affect that instance, not the other instances!**
- Instances can be deployed on a single element by its id (#myElement)
- Instances can be deployed on elements by class (.foo) - this is what is not working

**Here is my JQUERY code:**

```
(function($){

$.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
    // support multiple elements
    if (this.length > 1){
        this.each(function() { $(this).myPlugin(options) });
        return this;
    }

    // -- private variables --
    var $this = $(this);

    // default settings
    var defaults = { 
            initialText: 'I have been initialized'
        };
    // Merge defaults with setup options
    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    // Protect final options, placing inside jQuery element data 
    $this.data('myPlugSettings', options);

    // Shortcut var to access option data
    var settings = $this.data('myPlugSettings');

    // private methods
    var fooPrivate = function() {
        // do something private ...
    };

    // public methods        
    this.changeText = function(param) {
        $this.text(param);
    };

    // Constructor
    this.init = function() {
        $this.text( settings.initialText );
        // Return this for chainability?
        return this;
    };

    return this.init();
}
})(jQuery);



// globals

_ = {
    myPlugin: null,
    myPluginTwo: null,
    myPluginFoo: null
}


// Button Event handlers

$("#btnLoadPlugs").click(function(e) {
    _.myPlugin = $('#single').myPlugin({
        initialText: "Custom initial text" 
    });
    _.myPluginTwo = $('#anotherSingle').myPlugin();
    _.myPluginFoo  = $('.foo').myPlugin();
});

$("#btnGoSingle").click(function(e) {
    _.myPlugin.changeText(" Worked on single ID ");
});

$("#btnGoAnotherSingle").click(function(e) {
    _.myPluginTwo.changeText(" Worked again here ");
});

$("#btnGoFoo").click(function(e) {
    // THIS FALLS OVER ???????????
    _.myPluginFoo.changeText(" foos get this ");
});
```

[My JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dkg5m9h/4/) here makes the issue very easy to understand.

Comment: you return `this` and nothing else runs? `if (this.length > 1){
        this.each(function() { $(this).myPlugin(options) });
        return this;
    }`

Comment: Yea!!! So... we remove `return this` from the above and it works as expected! Only snag is that it breaks chain-ability in that situation, right - but... guess you can't have your cake and eat it! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**

`_.myPluginFoo` looses the reference to jQuery Objects with `changeText` method.

```
// support multiple elements
if (this.length > 1){
    this.each(function() { $(this).myPlugin(options) });

    // Send the collection back.
    return this;
}
```

**Just to get it to work**

```
// This will work, but this is not exactly what you have intended.
_.myPluginFoo.each(function(key, value) {
    $(value).myPlugin().changeText('Hello');
});
```

**Why?**

This is an expected behavior of Sizzle selector engine, the `$('#unique')` call will return an instance of jQuery Collection with a single *HTMLElement*, accessible by `$('#unique')[0]`.

By modifying `$('#unique')` as `this` inside `$.fn.myPlugin`, you will get a resulting object with `changeThext` property.

`$('.foo').myPlugin()` is resulting in `this.length > 1 // true`

You will easily notice the difference by debugging the following code:

```
$("#btnLoadPlugs").click(function(e) {
    // ...

    console.log(_.myPluginTwo); // Single object.
    console.log(_.myPluginFoo); // A collection, without changeText method.
});
```

`$.data` protection that you 're using is not very effective.

**The better way**

Also you could implement something like `$('.foo').myPlugin('changeText', 'new text')` if that makes sense.

Have a look at [jQuery Boilerplate](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate), that'sone of the best things about jQuery plugins.

Comment: Thank you for this. Really great answer. JQuery Boilerplate linked above offers some great solutions too.